# AWS ASG Error State transition reason Server.InternalError

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, aws-auto-scaling

Error:-
State transition reason: Server.InternalError
Client.InternalError: Client error on launch

When using the launch  template to launch the instance it is working fine but if i use ASG with launch template getting above error on ec2 instance.

[image]

Kms Key policy used for the ebs

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Enable IAM User Permissions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx:root"
            },
            "Action": "kms:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Allow administration of the key",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx:role/core-CloudformationStackAdmin",
                    "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx:root",
                    "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx:role/core-ServiceCatalogLaunchAdmin",
                    "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx:role/core-AccountAdmin=fGLB@000"
                ]
            },
            "Action": [
                "kms:Create*",
                "kms:Describe*",
                "kms:Enable*",
                "kms:List*",
                "kms:Put*",
                "kms:Update*",
                "kms:Revoke*",
                "kms:Disable*",
                "kms:Get*",
                "kms:Delete*",
                "kms:ScheduleKeyDeletion",
                "kms:CancelKeyDeletion"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Allow use of the key",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx:role/core-CloudformationStackAdmin",
                    "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx:root",
                    "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx:role/core-ServiceCatalogLaunchAdmin",
                    "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx:role/core-AccountAdmin=fGLB@I+000"
                ]
            },
            "Action": [
                "kms:DescribeKey",
                "kms:Encrypt",
                "kms:Decrypt",
                "kms:ReEncrypt*",
                "kms:GenerateDataKey",
                "kms:GenerateDataKeyWithoutPlaintext"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "Bool": {
                    "kms:GrantIsForAWSResource": "true"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Allow attachment of persistent resources",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx:role/core-CloudformationStackAdmin",
                    "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx:root",
                    "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx:role/core-ServiceCatalogLaunchAdmin",
                    "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx:role/core-AccountAdmin=fGLB@000"
                ]
            },
            "Action": [
                "kms:CreateGrant",
                "kms:ListGrants",
                "kms:RevokeGrant"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "Bool": {
                    "kms:GrantIsForAWSResource": "true"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Allow use of the key for Cloudwatch Log Groups Encryption",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "logs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": [
                "kms:Encrypt*",
                "kms:Decrypt*",
                "kms:ReEncrypt*",
                "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
                "kms:Describe*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "ArnEquals": {
                    "kms:EncryptionContext:aws:logs:arn": "arn:aws:logs:eu-west-1:xxxxxxxx:log-group:*"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

output of the instance :-

```
 {
        "Reservations": [
            {
                "Instances": [
                    {
                        "Monitoring": {
                            "State": "pending"
                        },
                        "PublicDnsName": "",
                        "StateReason": {
                            "Message": "Client.InternalError: Client error on launch",
                            "Code": "Client.InternalError"
                        },
                        "State": {
                            "Code": 48,
                            "Name": "terminated"
                        },
                        "EbsOptimized": true,
                        "LaunchTime": "2021-11-08T11:38:29.000Z",
                        "ProductCodes": [],
                        "CpuOptions": {
                            "CoreCount": 8,
                            "ThreadsPerCore": 2
                        },
                        "StateTransitionReason": "Server.InternalError",
                        "InstanceId": "i-0a266c694eb414f70",
                        "EnaSupport": true,
                        "ImageId": "ami-0ed588d6f749dcf28",
                        "PrivateDnsName": "",
                        "SecurityGroups": [],
                        "ClientToken": "2c45f3fd-5ea9-acd3-d703-c39a55955c94",
                        "InstanceType": "m5.4xlarge",
                        "CapacityReservationSpecification": {
                            "CapacityReservationPreference": "open"
                        },
                        "NetworkInterfaces": [],
                        "Placement": {
                            "Tenancy": "default",
                            "GroupName": "",
                            "AvailabilityZone": "eu-west-1a"
                        },
                        "Hypervisor": "xen",
                        "BlockDeviceMappings": [],
                        "Architecture": "x86_64",
                        "RootDeviceType": "ebs",
                        "RootDeviceName": "/dev/sda1",
                        "VirtualizationType": "hvm",
                        "Tags": [
                            {
                                "Value": "False",
                                "Key": "AutoShutdown"
                            },
                            {
                                "Value": "False",
                                "Key": "AutoStart"
                            },
                            {
                                "Value": "AutoScalingGroup",
                                "Key": "aws:cloudformation:logical-id"
                            },
                            {
                                "Value": "lt-0014c04827c2647b7",
                                "Key": "aws:ec2launchtemplate:id"
                            },
                            {
                                "Value": "True",
                                "Key": "RunAtWeekends"
                            },
                            {
                                "Value": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:9887878787:stack/ppe-devops-ecs-06/d5763820-4087-11ec-933b-02d79c55316d",
                                "Key": "aws:cloudformation:stack-id"
                            },
                            {
                                "Value": "1",
                                "Key": "aws:ec2launchtemplate:version"
                            },
                            {
                                "Value": "True",
                                "Key": "KeepMe"
                            },
                            {
                                "Value": "True",
                                "Key": "SaveIfOrphaned"
                            },
                            {
                                "Value": "ppe-devops-ecs-06-asg",
                                "Key": "aws:autoscaling:groupName"
                            },
                            {
                                "Value": "ppe-devops-ecs-06",
                                "Key": "aws:cloudformation:stack-name"
                            }
                        ],
                        "HibernationOptions": {
                            "Configured": false
                        },
                        "AmiLaunchIndex": 0
                    }
                ],
                "ReservationId": "r-014c8f943e5ca3655",
                "RequesterId": "178953610797",
                "Groups": [],
                "OwnerId": "9887878787"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have an instance ID and the AWS CLI? If so run `aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-id INSTANCEID` and add the output to the question please - this is related to your EBS volumes most likely

Comment: Do you use KMS encryption for your instance's volume?

Comment: Thank you Ermiya Eskandary. thank you  Marcin. I have added the comments.

Comment: any help here on the above query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KMS key access was the issue. Granting the permission has resolved the issue.
When there are extra encrypted volume is attached then this can come as error

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have same error message `Client.InternalError: Client error on launch`
I tried to add permissions to KMS key for EBS but with same result.
Here is one of my many configurations:

```
KmsKeyEbs:
Type: "AWS::KMS::Key"
Properties:
  Description: "KMS Key to enctypt and decrypt EBS volumes."
  KeyPolicy:
    Version: '2012-10-17'
    Statement:
     - Sid: "Allow administration of the key"
       Effect: Allow
       Principal:
         AWS: 
          - !Sub 'arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:root'
          - !Sub 'arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/aws-service-role/autoscaling.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForAutoScaling'
       Action:
        - 'kms:*'
       Resource: '*'
     - Sid: "Allow usage of the key"
       Effect: Allow
       Principal:
        AWS: '*'
       Action:
        - 'kms:Encrypt'
        - 'kms:Decrypt'
        - 'kms:ReEncrypt*'
        - 'kms:GenerateDataKey*'
        - 'kms:CreateGrant'
        - 'kms:RevokeGrant'
        - 'kms:List*'
        - 'kms:Describe*'
        - 'kms:Get*'
       Resource: '*'
```

EDIT:

In case this solution doesn't work, please check your AMI's if there was change. In my case AMI was encrypted after some time without any notice from AMI provider.

Comment: You are answering a question with other answer. Please avoid doing that.